# Signing raw transaction AssertionError: The field v must have byte length of 1

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, ethereumjs

I have followed every option present in net to do Raw transaction I have followed

> ethereumjs-tx

```
let resData = {};
var Tx = require('ethereumjs-tx')
var privateKey = new Buffer('0xe331b6d69882b4cb4ea581d88e0b604039a3de5967688d3dcffdd2270c0fd109', 'hex')
var gasPrice = privateWeb3.eth.gasPrice;
var gasPriceHex = privateWeb3.toHex(gasPrice);
var nonce = privateWeb3.eth.getTransactionCount(req.body.fromAddress);
var nonceHex = privateWeb3.toHex(nonce);
var rawTx = {
    nonce: nonceHex,
    gasPrice: gasPriceHex,
    gasLimit: '0x2710000000',
    to: req.body.toAddress,
    from: req.body.fromAddress,
    data: '0x7f7465737432000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000600057',
    chainId: req.body.chain
}

var tx = new Tx(rawTx)
console.log(tx.v);
tx.sign(privateKey)

var serializedTx = tx.serialize()
console.log(serializedTx.toString('hex'))

privateWeb3.eth.sendRawTransaction(serializedTx.toString('hex'), function(err, hash) {
    //  if (!err)
        console.log("hiii", err, hash); // "0x7f9fade1c0d57a7af66ab4ead79fade1c0d57a7af66ab4ead7c2c2eb7b11a91385"
});
```

This approach give me error in `tx.sign(privateKey)`

> AssertionError: The field v must have byte length of 1
>       at Transaction.setter [as v] (node_modules/ethereumjs-util/index.js:609:9)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may be caused by unexpectedly large `chainId`.
It is used to compute `tx.v`.

See [EIP155](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/155):

> v = CHAIN_ID * 2 + 35 or v = CHAIN_ID * 2 + 36

And [ethereumjs-tx source](https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-tx/blob/b9855577c8a86a65235c6c9e8eeaee93d23983ec/index.js#L219):

```
// sig.v = 28

if (this._chainId > 0) {
  sig.v += this._chainId * 2 + 8
}
```

So, to fit `v` into a single byte, your `chainId` must be less than `0x6d` 
 (109 dec).

Ropsten has `chainId = 3`, mainnet has `chainId = 1`.

Comment: I have use ChainId 1300 as 1300 is my Network id for ethereum blockchain in private network . @max How can i get chainId for private net?

Comment: `chainId` can be specified in genesis.json. E.g. `networkID` option in parity: https://github.com/ethcore/parity/wiki/Chain-specification and `--networkid` command line option in geth.

Comment: I think @max you are right . Let me try

Comment: it is saying Error: Invalid sender
    at Object.InvalidResponse error . Can you point out some thing about this error.

Comment: It's hard to say. Can you please show your complete setup? Maybe it worth posting new question with your private net config and minimal reproducible code.

Answer (score 0):

> var privateKey = new Buffer('0xe331b6d69882b4cb4ea581d88e0b604039a3de5967688d3dcffdd2270c0fd109', 'hex')

..you need to strip the `0x` hex prefix:
`new Buffer('e331b6d69882b4cb4ea581d88e0b604039a3de5967688d3dcffdd2270c0fd109', 'hex')`

ps) you can also get rid of `rawTx.from`.. it has no meaning and will be ignored. the raw transaction is sent "from" the address corresponding to the `privateKey` used to sign it